# Why match_phrase_prefix query returns wrong results with diffrent length of phrase?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have very simple query:

```
POST /indexX/document/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "surname": "grab"
    }
  }
}
```

with mapping:

```
"surname": {
  "type": "string",
  "analyzer": "polish",
  "copy_to": [
    "full_name"
  ]
}
```

and definition for index (I use Stempel (Polish) Analysis for Elasticsearch plugin):

```
POST /indexX
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym" : {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonyms.txt"
          },
          "polish_stop": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords_path": "analysis/stopwords.txt"
          },  
          "polish_my_stem": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "rules_path": "analysis/stems.txt"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "polish_with_synonym": {
            "tokenizer":  "standard",
            "filter": [
              "synonym",
              "lowercase",
              "polish_stop",
              "polish_stem",
              "polish_my_stem"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For this query I get **zero** results. When I change phrase to **GRA** or **GRABA** it returns 1 result (GRABARZ is the surname). Why is this happening?

I tried max_expansions with values even as high as 1200 and that didn't help.

Comment: could you post the definition `polish` analyzer ?

Comment: could you post the stopwords  & synonyms ? a wild guess is there is `grab` as a stopword or there is a synonym for `grab` ?

Comment: oooh :) I've checked that already. These files do not contain word 'grab'.

Comment: what does `get   indexX/_analyze?analyzer=polish&text=grab`  return . Also in the mapping you had analyzer as `polish` and setting shows `polish_with_synonym` i guess it is similar  without synonyms ?

Comment: {
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "grabić",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}

Comment: so that is the reason you are not getting a match for some reason `grab` is being converted to `grabic` and that is not a prefix match . Just to comfirm this is the issue  set search analyzer to `standard`  in `match_phrase_prefix` example: `{"query":{"match_phrase_prefix":{"surname":{"query":"grab","analyzer":"standard"}}}}` and check if you now get results

Comment: In this case I was looking for polish name. Mapping for surname and for firstname shouldn't be analyzed with 'polish analyzer'. Thanks for the lead keety!

Comment: np ,good luck! (and 15 more characters to go .....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first glance, your analyzer stems the search term ("grab") and renders it unusable ("grabić").

Without going into details on how to resolve this, please consider getting rid of polish analyzer here. We are talking about people's names, not "ordinary" polish words.

I saw different techniques used in this case: multi-field searches, fuzzy searches, phonetic searches, dedicated plugins.

Some links:
    https://www.elastic.co/blog/multi-field-search-just-got-better
    http://www.basistech.com/fuzzy-search-names-in-elasticsearch/
    https://www.found.no/play/gist/6c6434c9c638a8596efa

But I guess in case of polish names some kind of prefix query on non-analyzed field would suffice...

Comment: Thanks for showing me the phonetic approach to this problem. Note for me for the future... Always RTFM :D